# Python-Docx Columns

Tags: python, docx, python-docx

I am trying to format a piece of text into columns.
There are two aspects that I am trying to achieve:

1. I am trying to have multiple sections within a page. The first paragraph to have only one column layout and the rest of the paragraph to be formatted as two column text. I have tried creating different sections, then add paragraph and then create another section with two column layout, but no success. I am ending up messing up layouts.

   2. When I create two column layouts, the second column is getting populated with text only after first column is fully populated. This means, if the text is only long enough to populate first column, I am getting a blank second row, instead of auto adjusting the length to split it into 2 columns easily.Is there a way to achieve that?

In any case, I am creating sections and 2 column lay out as per below suggestion:
[How to programatically implement Columns in page layout as of in MS Word using python-docx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30707120/how-to-programatically-implement-columns-in-page-layout-as-of-in-ms-word-using-p)

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Were you able to do this? What's your solution?
can you share some code snippets?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution - it needed to add me a section break at the end of columns.
This was just as good as adding a new section as per below:

```
section = document.add_section(WD_SECTION.CONTINUOUS)
```