# Python excel and word

Tags: python, openpyxl, docx

I have an excel file from which I take information and upload it to word, but the problem is that in Word I need the information to be displayed in tables in two, but I have one.

I have this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpNnD.jpg
And I need it like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1b8DH.jpg

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import openpyxl
from docx import Document
from docx.enum.text import WD_PARAGRAPH_ALIGNMENT
from docx.shared import Inches, Cm

# Create the main window
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

# Open a file dialog to select the Excel file
file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Select Excel file", filetypes=(("Excel files", "*.xlsx"), ("All files", "*.*")))

# Open the Excel file and select the worksheet
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_path)
sheet = wb['Sheet1']

doc = Document()

# Create tables
for i in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
    if sheet[f'B{i}'].value:
        for j in range(int(sheet[f'F{i}'].value)):
            table = doc.add_table(rows=6, cols=2)
            table.style = 'Table Grid'
            table.autofit = False

            # Modify the width of the first column
            for cell in table.columns[0].cells:
                cell.width = Cm(2.5)

            # Modify the width of the second column
            for cell in table.columns[1].cells:
                cell.width = Cm(5.5)

            # Add a blank paragraph between each table
            doc.add_paragraph("\n")

            nos = sheet[f"B{i}"].value if sheet[f"B{i}"].value else "N/A"
            nom_nr = sheet[f"J{i}"].value if sheet[f"J{i}"].value else "N/A"
            kods = sheet[f"D{i}"].value if sheet[f"D{i}"].value else "N/A"
            pas_nr = sheet[f"K{i}"].value if sheet[f"K{i}"].value else "N/A"

            table.cell(0, 0).text = "Nos."
            table.cell(0, 1).text = str(nos)
            table.cell(1, 0).text = "Nom. Nr."
            table.cell(1, 1).text = str(nom_nr)
            table.cell(2, 0).text = "Kods"
            table.cell(2, 1).text = str(kods)
            table.cell(3, 0).text = "Pas. Nr."
            table.cell(3, 1).text = str(pas_nr)
            table.cell(4, 0).text = "Daudzums"
            table.cell(4, 1).text = "1000"
            table.cell(5, 0).text = "Izpildītājs"
            table.cell(5, 1).text = "SIA “STS Group”\nCeļāres 2B, Spilve, Babītes pag.\nTel. 29211780"

# Save the Word document
doc.save('data.docx')
```

here is the program code

Comment: Possibly related to : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30707120/how-to-programatically-implement-columns-in-page-layout-as-of-in-ms-word-using-p

Comment: Along with the other comment. You can first create a table 1 row, 2 columns, i.e. 2 cells, then put your first table in the first cell and the second table in the second cell.